# Call C function inside a C extension in Python

Tags: python, c, wrapper

I've tried to make a C extension to Python. My problem is that I have C function calls inside the C function I have made a C extension for. For example I am using C functions in pmd.h and usb1024LS.h inside these C functions. When I try running my script, I get errors like "undefined symbol: hid_init". Where hid_init is a function.
I have tried running the program in a c main program, and it works.
How do I call C functions from inside other C functions which have an extension?

Thanks!

My code:
test.py - test script:

```
import ctypes
import myTest_1024LS

ctypes_findInterface = ctypes.CDLL('/home/oysmith/NetBeansProjects/MCCDAQ/usb1024LS_with_py/myTest_1024LS.so').findInterface
ctypes_findInterface.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
ctypes_findInterface.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]

ctypes_findInterface()
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name="myTest_1024LS", version="0.0", ext_modules = [Extension("myTest_1024LS", ["myTest_1024LS.c"])])
```

myTest_1024LS.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

#include "pmd.h"
#include "usb-1024LS.h"
#include "myTest_1024LS.h"

void findInterface(void){
int interface;
hid_return ret;
ret = hid_init();
if (ret != HID_RET_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "hid_init failed with return code %d\n", ret);
        exit(1);
}

if ((interface = PMD_Find_Interface(&hid, 0, USB1024LS_PID)) >= 0) {
        printf("USB 1024LS Device is found! interface = %d\n", interface);
} else if ((interface = PMD_Find_Interface(&hid, 0, USB1024HLS_PID)) >= 0) {
        printf("USB 1024HLS Device is found! interface = %d\n", interface);
} else {
        fprintf(stderr, "USB 1024LS and USB 1024HLS not found.\n");
        exit(1);
}
}

PyDoc_STRVAR(myTest_1024LS__doc__, "myTes_1024LS point evaluation kernel");
PyDoc_STRVAR(findInterface__doc__, "find device");

static PyObject *py_findInterface(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);

static PyMethodDef wrapper_methods[] = {
{"findInterface", py_findInterface, METH_VARARGS, findInterface__doc__},
{NULL, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initwrapper(void){
Py_InitModule3("wrapper", wrapper_methods, myTest_1024LS__doc__);

}

static PyObject *py_findInterface(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){

if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "")){
    return NULL;
}
findInterface();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to run a Python script which calls a C function which then shall call a Python function again?  If I've got that right:  How about rewriting that inner Python function in C as well?  After all, I guess you want to achieve sth by switching to C (probably speed?), and then stepping back into Python might spoil that fun.

Comment: No, I have a Python script which call a C function which call another C functionm, as you can see in myTest_1024LS.c. The C function calls inside the C function are calls to usb device drivers. I would not like to write C extenisons for all the driver functions, because there are many of them.

Comment: I see.  How did you take care that the needed libraries for the USB drivers are linked to your code?

Comment: Probably I have to make some kind of shared library or something, but I dont know how Python will be able to see them. I'am totally new to the C extension thing, so I dont have a clue on how to link the USB drivers to my code. I guess thats what I need some help to understand!

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the C code. It seems to be some hybrid between a Python extension module intended to be imported as module and a shared library intended to be used via `ctypes`!? That's kind of odd. Usually you do either one or the other, not both.

Comment: Yeah, I dont know why I did this hybrid ctypes extension thing. I removed the ctypes part and did some changes to the test.py and setup.py file. Then the program seems to work!

Answer (score 2):

When building C extensions which themselves have to be linked against other shared libraries you'll have to tell which ones to link against in the `setup.py`.  In this case at least the library which exports the `hid_init()` function.  See the Python documentation for more details and examples: [Building C and C++ Extensions with distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html). The second example contains arguments to link an extra library to the extension module.

---

The `ctypes` ”declarations” are wrong: `void` is not the same as a void pointer (`void*`). The `findInterface()` C function has neither arguments nor a return value, which is ”declared” as:

```
ctypes_findInterface.argtypes = []
ctypes_findInterface.restype = None
```